# Using XMLHttpRequest synchronously in IE9 does not return any data

Tags: javascript

This is the code i have used:

```
if(window.XDomainRequest) {xml_add_http = new XDomainRequest();}
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xml_add_http=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xml_add_http=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var main_url    =   "http://localhost/date/check.php";
xml_add_http.open("GET",main_url,false);
xml_add_http.send(null);
var xml_add_Doc=xml_add_http.responseText;
console.log(xml_add_Doc);
}
```

On chrome or firefox in concole window it returns:

> {"datetime":"Thu, 04 Jul 2013 20:11:21 +0000"}

But in internet explorer 9 it only returns:

> LOG:

Comment: How do you load the script in your browser? i.e. what url do you use? You may want to check for errors in the request object.

Comment: i want to load json using this code and i am able to do it in chrome or firefox using this code but in ie9 this code is not  working.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? You can certainly use AJAX in IE9, and since Microsoft invented it, it may be Chrome and FireFox (and you) that are doing it wrong.

Comment: why would you prefer XDomainRequest to XMLHttpRequest when both are available?

Comment: @dandavis thank you...it works now...anyway i have used XDomainRequest for IE8 but its nor fruitful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing XDomainRequest from the code, it works on ie.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XDomainRequest this is a good read because it should work in IE8 & 9 but there are a few requirements